# Passing array as argument and swapping the data - unexpected data

Tags: c, arrays, function, pointers, swap

When I pass the argument in swap function, I am expecting the output for indices `a[0]` and `a[1]`. But the output is showing the data from `a[1]` and `a[2]` respectively.

But why? And how to improve it?

Below is my code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int add(int *array,int max );
void swap(int *array,int max,int *x,int *y);

int  main()
{
    int sum,i,j=0,a[10],max;

    scanf("%d",&max);

    for(i=0;i<max;i++)
    {
        scanf("%d",&a[i]);
    }

    for(i=0;i<max;i++)
    {
        printf(" %d ",a[i]);
    }

    printf("\n");

    //for(i=0;i<max;i++)
    {
        swap(a,max,&a[0],&a[1]);
    }
    sum=add(a,max);  // array name is same as address of array//or sum=add(&a[0],max);
    printf("%d",sum);
}

int add(int *array,int max)
{
    int sum=0,i=0;
    while(i<max)
    {
        sum=sum +array[i];
        i++;
    }
    return sum;
}

void swap(int *a,int max, int *x,int *y)
{
    int i;
    /* int temp=0;

    temp=a[*x];
    a[*x]=a[*y];
    a[*y]=temp;*/
    printf("\n%d %d",a[*x],a[*y]);
    for(i=0;i<max;i++)
    {
        printf("\n %d",a[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in the below line

```
printf("\n%d %d",a[*x],a[*y]);
```

With a call to `swap()` like

```
swap(a,max,&a[0],&a[1]);
```

if `a[0]` or `a[1]` has a value more than `10`, you are accessing the array out of bounds. Please check and correct your logic.

FWIW,

> *But the output is showing the data from a[1] and a[2] respectively*

That is because, most probably, `a[0]` contains `1` and `a[1]` contains `2

Comment: it is not out of bound since i always access array for i<10, also a[0]=1,a[1]=2,a[2]=3 and so on upto a[4]=5,as i take max =5. sorry i am new to programming

Comment: @deepakpandey when asking for user input, how you can gurantee `a[0]==1` always?

Comment: @deepakpandey nothing to be sorry friend, just think logically. :-)

Comment: i basically want to send 2 indices of array to swap function using pointers . how to do that . and isn't taking data using scanf  guarantee the data that user entered to be at that indices.

Comment: @deepakpandey I was talking about the _value_ that the user will enter. You can't be sure about that. Atleast, you shouldn't be writing a program _assuming_ that. :-)

Answer (score 0):

i tried and this is working fine now .thanks

```
int add(int *array,int max );
void swap(int *array,int max,int *x,int *y);

  int  main()
  {
    int sum,i,j=0,a[10],max;

     printf("enter the size \n");

      scanf(" %d",&max);

      for(i=0;i<max;i++)
    {
        scanf("%d",&a[i]);
        }

          for(i=0;i<max;i++)
    {
        printf(" data entered a[%d] = %d \n ",i,a[i]);
        }

printf("\n");


printf("%d",&a[1]);

         //for(i=0;i<max;i++)
    {

      swap(a,max,&a[0],&a[1]);

      }
      sum=add(a,max);  // array name is same as address of array//or sum=add(&a[0],max);
       printf("%d",sum);
}

  int add(int *array,int max)
  {
      int sum=0,i=0;
      while(i<max)
      {


     sum=sum +array[i];
  i++;}
  return sum;
  }

void swap(int *a,int max, int *x,int *y)
{
 int i,temp;
  temp=*y;
   *y=*x;
    *x=temp;

    printf("\n%d %d",*x,y);
     for(i=0;i<max;i++)
    {
        printf("\n %d",a[i]);
    }

printf("\n");

}
```